# How to set some values of list as optional in Spring mapping?

Tags: java, excel, spring, mapping

I want to make some values of the following list as optional, the following mapping is done to read the columns from Excel sheet and store them into DB. But some columns may not come every time in the Excel sheet, so I want to make some columns say `remark12` and `remarks13` as optional:

```
<property name="remarkColumns">
    <list>
      <value>remarks1</value>
      <value>remarks2</value>
      <value>remarks3</value>
      <value>remarks4</value>
      <value>remarks5</value>
      <value>remarks6</value>
   </list>
</property>
```

Please help with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Either

1. Use a Map rather than a list, key: String column name, value: Boolean Optional.
2. Use some sort of holder object for two values (Tuple2 or Pair) - a String and a Boolean. One should be the column name and the other whether or not it is optional.
3. (Worst option, imho). Use a prefix on the column name to indicate optionality and parse the name String in your own code.

Comment: Any other way, I can make  any value optional?

Comment: Yeah, you can have two lists - the second one can represent the optional values. java.util.Optional isn't appropriate here btw.